# Locally-nameless representation: normal order & opening with a bound variable

Tags: lambda-calculus, normalization

This question concerns the representation used in Arthur Charguéraud's paper [“The locally nameless representation”](https://www.chargueraud.org/research/2009/ln/main.pdf) and is somehow a follow-up on [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/39089/51030), where it is asked about the normalization of terms under a binder, at the example of the following term (for technical reasons, I use **one based indices**):

$$\lambda((\lambda\lambda(2 \; 1)) \; 1)$$

Beta-reductions in this representations supposedly (and contrary to the answer to the linked question) are done without need of introducing fresh variable names, because we can replace a variable opening + substitution combination

$$((\lambda \; t ) \; u)  \longrightarrow_\beta [x \mapsto u] \; t^{x} \qquad (x \text{ fresh in } t)$$

by simple “term” opening

$$((\lambda \; t ) \; u)  \longrightarrow_\beta t^{u},$$

where $t^{u} = \mathtt{open}(1, u, t)$ (see p. 10 in the paper).  `open` can be implemented as follows, trying to exactly follow the definition there and Charguérot's [reference implementation](http://www.chargueraud.org/viewcoq.php?sFile=softs%2Fln%2Fsrc%2FSTLC_Core_Tutorial.v) in Coq:

```
open k u (Bvar i)    = if k == i then u else (Bvar i)
open k u (Fvar x)    = Fvar x
open k u (Abs t1)    = Abs (open (k + 1) u t1)
open k u (App t1 t2) = App (open k u t1) (open k u t2)
```

Now, reducing the example term in (what I think is) normal order will result in the following steps:

\begin{align*}
\mathtt{reduce}\; \lambda((\lambda\lambda(2 \; 1)) \; 1) &= \lambda(\mathtt{reduce} \; ((\lambda\lambda(2 \; 1)) \; 1)) \\
&= \lambda(\mathtt{open} \; 1 \; 1 \; (\lambda(2 \; 1))) \\
&= \lambda( \lambda (\mathtt{open} \; 2 \; 1 \; (2 \; 1))) \\
&= \lambda( \lambda ((\mathtt{open} \; 2 \; 1 \; 2) \; (\mathtt{open} \; 2 \; 1 \; 1))) \\
&= \lambda \lambda (1 \; 1)
\end{align*}

This is, however, the wrong result -- the answer should have been $\lambda \lambda (2 \; 1)$ (essentially, just eta converting the term).  The problem lies in the second-last line, where the bound $1$ from outside  replaces the inner $2$ without being properly changed.

Appearently, `open` in this form is not made for normal order, due to the fact that unlike evaluation in de Bruijn representation, the substituted term is not shifted.  In fact, I found the following comment on top of Charguéraud's implementation of `open` (called `open_rec` there):

> We make several simplifying assumptions in defining [open_rec]. First,
>   we assume that the argument [u] is locally closed.  This assumption
>   simplifies the implementation since we do not need to shift indices in
>   [u] when passing under a binder.  Second, we assume that this function
>   is initially called with index zero and that zero is the only unbound
>   index in the term.  This eliminates the need to possibly subtract one
>   in the case of indices.

Of course, the assumption of local closedness holds only when we do something like call-by-name, where terms under binders are not reduced.  My solution was to change `open` to the following `open'`, which “inlines” shifting of bound variables when they are inserted (which can be done easily, since we keep track of the number of binders anyway with `k`):

```
open' k (Bvar j) (Bvar i) = if k == i then (Bvar j + k - 1) else (Bvar i)
open' k u (Bvar i)    = if k == i then u else (Bvar i)
open' k u (Fvar x)    = Fvar x
open' k u (Abs t1)    = Abs (open' (k + 1) u t1)
open' k u (App t1 t2) = App (open' k u t1) (open' k u t2)
```

The questions I have are:

- Is my reasoning correct?
- Does `open'` correctly fix the problem when the assumptions do not hold (ie, when used in normal order reduction)?
- Does `open'` preserve the properties and correctness of `open` when the original assumptions hold?